# In Tetris Battle, how do you "overwhelm your opponent"?

Tags: tetris, tetris-battle

In Tetris Battle on Facebook, by some condition, the game tells you that you've "overwhelmed your opponent", and it grants you two stars rather than one.

What is that condition?

Answer (score 2):

Your ranking at the end of the game determines how many stars you earn. Your ranking is determined by the following categories:

1. **Number of KO's:** If you force an opponent to the top of his screen by dropping blocks, you will earn a "KO." While this is usually the determining factor in terms of wins, when playing with multiple players, if several players KO someone, other categories are considered.
2. **Number of lines sent:** If you send more lines than your opponent(s).
3. **Tertromino height:** How high your Tetromino reach in your matrix. The lower the stack, the more points you will earn.

If you beat your opponents in all three of the above categories, you will earn three stars ("overpowering the opponent").

Comment: Nope, that doesn't appear to be it either... hmm

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka are you playing 2P or 6P? This only works in 6P if you beat ALL of your opponents in all three categories.

Comment: 2P. I've been paying attention to what's happening, but even when I beat my opponent in all 3 conditions, I don't necessarily get 2 stars... confusing D:

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka I'm not sure you can get this in 2P as it makes cheating a lot easier (have someone idle while you KO them)... Only in modes (6P Battle and probably 4P Sprint) of more than 2 players can you "overpower" you opponents. I believe you will only earn bonus stars for only the first 20 ranks.

Comment: I'm positive you can do it in 2P -- I don't play anything else. Maybe the rules are different for 2P? I see what you mean that people can cheat, but it looks like they haven't accounted for that, and knowing the conditions, you certainly could do cheat.

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka I know you can do it, too, but I don't think you will get the bonus stars.

Comment: You get two rather than three stars.

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka I did some testing in 2P with another account (limited to what I could manage with my energy canister)... I think it might have something to do with the number of lines sent. I don't think that number is based on what you have vs. what your opponent has, but rather what your results vs. the average number of lines sent for that rank.

Comment: Hmm... that could be it. I got two stars earlier today, but I didn't notice doing anything out of the ordinary other than that I played pretty well.